future transaction tries to replace pending
I have an address A which I have funded with ETH. Now I want to crate a transaction to send the funds to a different address B. Creating and signing seems to work as I can decode the transaction and all values seem to be good.
Broadcasting the transaction on etherscan.io leads to the following error:
Unable To Broadcast Txn : {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"future transaction tries to replace pending"}}
Broadcasting the transaction on blockcypher.com lead to the following error:
Error validating transaction: Transaction [txhash] orphaned, missing reference 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.
can someone tell me what might be the problem?

Add more details about the transaction . Also have you broadcasted  any previous transaction with the same nonce

I think you need to increase priority gas in order to replace a pending tx

Which chain are you trying to do this? Try including nonce in the transaction. You can fetch your account's latest nonce in web3.js from this function  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress)

thanks - at the end it was the nounce. didn´t knew that you MUST start with 0 (tried 1 and increased automatically) the nounce has to be increased with every transaction done by the referencing address? so even if all tx are broadcasted and confirmed I have to increase it for further transactions?

I am glad you resolved your issue. Can you please mark my comment  as answer.
